# How to compare two objects by class name or type (equivalent of Java's `getClass()` in C++)

Tags: c++, class, typeid

I'd like to compare two objects by their class name. The first object is of type `Card*` which points to a `MagicCard` object, and the second is of type `MagicCard` - a child class of `Card`. When I compare them with `typeid` it doesn't work:

```cpp
if (typeid(*(this->cards[index])) != typeid(card)) {
        //the first object is of type Card* inside a vector and points to a 
        MagicCard object
        //card is of type MagicCard
        return false;
        //this "if" check stops the method in case the types are different.

}
```

The comparison above should return that the objects are of the same type, because the the element in that position inside the vector I know that there is a function `getClass()` in Java so I am looking for some kind of an equivalent in C++ which compares objects by the derived class, not by the mother class.

EDIT: I changed the code to Peter's suggestion and added information why I need this check. It doesn't work yet.

Comment: If you want to check if the types are the same, you should use `==` to compare the `type_info` objects, not `!=`.   Your test succeeds if the types differ.    If `this->cards[index]` gives a pointer, and `card` is an object, your test needs to be `if (typeid(*(this->cards[index])) == typeid(card))`.

Comment: @Peter I use the `if` as a check - in case the objects are of a different type, the method returns false and everything ends there, otherwise I perform other actions, i.e. I make validation. The problem is that `typeid` returns that the first object is `4Card` and the second - `MagicCard`, even though they are both MagicCards. Therefore, even if the objects are of the same type, the method always returns false and doesn't procede to do what I want.

Comment: Read the last sentence of my previous comment again.

Comment: @Peter Unfortunately it didn't work. :-(

Comment: From that, it's likely your `Card` class is not polymorphic.

Comment: maybe [dynamic_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast)?

Comment: @Peter Yes, that was a problem. I made the base class virtual but now I can't create objects of the derived classes (probably a simple fix but I just couldn't put my finger on it). I guess I'll have to make separate vectors for all types instead. Thanks for all the tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's almost always incorrect to be looking at `typeid`.

You can get a `MagicCard *` from a `Card *` with `dynamic_cast`, and it will be a null pointer if the `Card *` doesn't point to a `MagicCard` object.

```
if (auto * magicCard = dynamic_cast<MagicCard>(cards[index])) {
    // do something with magicCard
}
```

However it is often better to add `virtual void doSomething()` to `Card`, and override it in `MagicCard`.

```
cards[index]->doSomething(); // no mention of MagicCard needed
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear how your `Card` and `MagicCard` classes are declared.
`typeid` does not work with non-polimorphistic classes according to [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid).

If you, for example got the following program, the output will be as shown in the comments next to the output line:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

class BaseNonPoly { };
class DerivedNonPoly : public BaseNonPoly { };
class BasePoly { virtual void foo() {} };
class DerivedPoly : public BasePoly { };

int main()
{
    BaseNonPoly baseNonPoly;
    DerivedNonPoly derivedNonPoly;
    BasePoly basePoly;
    DerivedPoly derivedPoly;
    
    BaseNonPoly& pBaseNonPoly = baseNonPoly;
    BaseNonPoly& pDerivedNonPoly = derivedNonPoly;
    BasePoly& pBasePoly = basePoly;
    BasePoly& pDerivedPoly = derivedPoly;
    
    
    std::cout << "typeid(baseNonPoly)=" << typeid(baseNonPoly).name() << std::endl; // typeid(baseNonPoly)=11BaseNonPoly
    std::cout << "typeid(derivedNonPoly)=" << typeid(derivedNonPoly).name() << std::endl; // typeid(derivedNonPoly)=14DerivedNonPoly
    std::cout << "typeid(basePoly)=" << typeid(basePoly).name() << std::endl; // typeid(basePoly)=8BasePoly
    std::cout << "typeid(derivedPoly)=" << typeid(derivedPoly).name() << std::endl; // typeid(derivedPoly)=11DerivedPoly
    
    std::cout << "typeid(pBaseNonPoly)=" << typeid(pBaseNonPoly).name() << std::endl; // typeid(pBaseNonPoly)=11BaseNonPoly
    std::cout << "typeid(pDerivedNonPoly)=" << typeid(pDerivedNonPoly).name() << std::endl; // typeid(pDerivedNonPoly)=11BaseNonPoly
    std::cout << "typeid(pBasePoly)=" << typeid(pBasePoly).name() << std::endl; // typeid(pBasePoly)=8BasePoly
    std::cout << "typeid(pDerivedPoly)=" << typeid(pDerivedPoly).name() << std::endl; // typeid(pDerivedPoly)=11DerivedPoly

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, the object of the non-polimorphic derived class `DerivedNonPoly`  without virtual method can not be identified as what it really is and returns the type of it's parent `BaseNonPoly` instead.

As in Caleth's answer mentioned, it is good practice to avoid special cases depending on concrete derived class types. Since this, however, can't always be avoided in an elegant way, it might be enough to use a unused virtual function or a virtual deconstructor to your `Card` and `MagicCard` class for `typeid` to work correctly.